# NUnit 3 test listeners

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm working on my first C# Selenium-NUnit project, but I have experience in Selenium-TestNG projects. And there was excellent solution for report building by implementing such methods as "onTestStart", "onTestSuccess", "OnTestFailure", "OnTestSkipped" etc of exiting test listener interfaces to realize various reactions on various cases.

Does NUnit contains any listener with similar rich functionality to catch all those events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The NUnit Test Engine supports extensions at various points. One such extension is a TestEventListener, which receives events from the engine. You would create an extension of your own, handling the `ITestEventListener` interface, and implementing the interface's sole method: `void OnTestEvent(string report)`.

The `report` argument is the string representation of an XML element. The name of the element specifies the nature of the event event and any attributes and nested elements give you the details. The following events are supported:

- `<start-run>`
- `<end-run>`
- `<test-suite>`
- `<end-suite>`  (Completion of a suite)
- `<start-test>`
- `<test-case>`  (Completion of a test case)
- `<test-output>`

This gives you a general idea of what may be accomplished in the extension. For details on implementation, see the [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/extensions/Writing-Engine-Extensions.html).